# How can I roll back my touchpad drivers to a previous version?

Tags: touchpad, drivers

I have a Lenovo z570 where I installed elementary OS. I installed Synaptic driver from X.org and the dependencies. After a reboot, I completely lost the ability to use my trackpad. Sometimes the physical buttons work, but no movement at all.

I would love to roll back to before I installed the driver when I had functionality.

Comment: What exactly did you installed? (and how?) What was the reason to install synaptic touch pad drivers if they were already working?

Comment: The main reason I was installing it was to try and get the scrolling feature I had in windows on the right hand side of the trackpad. I would drag my finger along the right side along the y-axis and whatever was selected would scroll. When I installed the driver, I read about two finger scrolling instead. Once the touchpad stopped working I realized that all the functionality I was enjoying before (two finger scrolling specifically) was after I had installed the driver, but before a reboot. Then I reasoned that it was already there, I had just not tried it before.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/x7driver.html#xorg-synaptics-driver
this is what I followed and installed...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367701/touchpad-stopped-working-out-of-the-blue) to reinstall the kernel and it is working great. I messed up installing the drivers from xorg and should not have as the functionality was already built into the kernel, I was just not understanding how! Thanks for all who read my question and were trying to help!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/367701/touchpad-stopped-working-out-of-the-blue